# Polling thread in Blazor

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, design-patterns, architecture, blazor

I am building a Blazor application with a REST API and Web interface. I will also have a monitoring part of the application that will poll data each second from a lot of different data sources. I have created a long running thread in a separate class that simply polls the data I want and it seems to be working fine. The application template I am using is a Blazor ASP.NET Server application. Simply like this:

```
 m_pollThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(PollThread))
 {
    IsBackground = true
 };
 m_pollThread.Start();
```

What I am wondering now is: is it completely wrong with respect to programming patterns to put this type of polling threads inside of the Blazor application itself? Is there some problems doing like this that will backfire later on (memory consumption, performance of the rest of the application)? The reason why I am asking is because as far as I know, Blazor and ASP.NET Core applications are general "on-request" and wakes up when something is requested, and not executing long-running endless polling tasks. I do not know if I could run that within IIS for instance.

Comment: If you setup your IIS app pool and web site correctly then yes : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization

Comment: why are you polling at all?  It's a horrible design decision when we have System.Reactive available to simply create subscriptions.

Comment: I agree that polling should be a last-resort kind of thing.

Comment: I am polling old field equipment and there is no way to setup subscriptions on such devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it completely wrong with respect to programming patterns to put this type of polling threads inside of the Blazor application itself?

Yes. It won't break immediately but it is asking for trouble.

The solution is easy though, ASP.NET core  lets you run [multiple Host threads very easily](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio).

The new worker template is probably the preferred way now but all you really need is

```
class MyPollingService : BackgroundService { ... }
```

and

```
services.AddHostedService<MyPollingService>();
```

Your gain is better integration with the framework and more control over Start and Stop etc.

Comment: If I am going to have lets say over 20 of these services (each monitoring a separate device independently from each other). Would I create one master-service MyPollingService as you wrote and that creates 20 PollChildService (where each spawns a PollThread)?

Comment: I would stay away from creating my own threads. Making 20 services sounds reasonable, try to do a.m.a.p. async.

Comment: And creating these services I would do in a for-loop ? like
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
services.AddHostedService<MyPollingService>();
}

Comment: No, that would be weird. Why would you want 20 identical services?  You would only get 1 though.

Comment: But I would need 20 identical background services just each single one with different IP for instance.

Comment: Then how about 1 service setting up 20 async calls ?

Comment: How is that possible? These 20 async "calls" all depends on different states of the signals they fetch. And they fetch data in different intervals. You mean I should set up Timers in that BackgroundService that calls async methods?

Comment: Maybe. The details depend very much on the kind of APIs to poll, the intervals, how much requests the Blazor app wil get etc.

Comment: For starters: why is this all in the same app? What will you do when the Browser looses its connection?

Comment: This is a Blazor Server application, I just assumed that these services running regardless if anyone is Browsing the web pages. I do not see what it has to do with Browser. My monitoring service will always run in the background (no browser, pure server), then I want Blazor to serve the aggregated values to the user whenever the user ask for it.

Comment: Is it still asking for trouble if I configure the Blazor application to be hosted as a Windows Service? When looking further I realized that I will also need to setup long-running subscriptions in a 3rd party library. So my application is rather a server service with Blazor web functionality. It would be ideal if I could create and handle my own threads.

Answer (score 0):

I built something similar for Pipeline pressure testing, and I only used one timer to read all of our devices in the test.

I can't post the class because it belongs to my last client, but basically I set a timer to run every 30 seconds (30000 milliseconds), so it is guaranteed to run at least one in a minute with this code:

```
        public int Minute { get; set; }

        public bool NewMinute
        {
            get
            {
                // initial value
                bool newMinute = DateTime.Now.Minute != this.Minute;

                // return value
                return newMinute;
            }
        }
```

Then in my timer tick event, I do a check

```
if (NewMinute)
{
    // store so I don't send again till the next minute
    Minute = DateTime.Now.Minute;

    // Get all temperature values
    GetTemperatureValues();
}
```

In my GetTemperatureValues method, I call off to some serial libraries, and I either get a value back or if I don't get a response back within 5 seconds, it bails.

Not sure if that gives you any guidance, but it did work for where I used to work, except for they bought the cheapest devices and they failed too often, but not the code.

Now this was all done in Windows Forms, Blazor is a different animal. You can use Timers in Blazor as I do in my Sprite component to animate it, and there is a Subscriber interface included in this Nuget package and sample project:

https://github.com/DataJuggler/DataJuggler.Blazor.Components

And here is a video that goes with it if you are bored: https://youtu.be/frtetHgfdIo

[image: Blazor Animation Sample]